# Hydrostatic Force

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

Struggling with this question: Find the force due to hydrostatic pressure on the side of a trough of length $L$ if the end is a semicircle of radius $R$ and it is filled to the top with a fluid of density $\rho$.

I worked out the width to $2\times\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}$ but do not know where to go from here

Comment: Well, why not follow what your textbook does, chop into horizontal slabs, and write down the integral like the examples in your textbook?

Comment: Width of what?!

Comment: @AjayMishra He is talking about the cross section. It's half of a disk. At depth $x$, the width is $2\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$.